# Manually Edit Collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm relatively new to Meteor and I was wondering how I manually edit the mongoDB for Meteor Collections.

If I declare a new collection on both the client and server:

```
People = new Meteor.Collection("people");
```

Then I create an array of names on the server and insert it into the collection:

```
var names = ["Dan", "Bob", "Sarah"];
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++)
{
    People.insert({name: names[i]}); 
}
```

How do I add fields to the database and/or change fields in the database manually for development purpose? If I retype the names in the 'names' array and relaunch the app, it doesn't update the database on the server like I expected it would.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the javascript developer console in chrome/safari or firebug in firefox**

while your app is running you can edit your names.

Your changes will be done live so you can debug and play around quite alot. Something like this might work:

```
People.find().fetch()
=> lists all the people
```

Edit one

```
People.update("_id value from above of the person", {$set:{name:"New Name"}})
```

**Why the method you're using isn't working:**

Meteor won't add the names again to the `People` collection if its already populated. So just run `meteor reset` to clear everything in your collection. And run meteor again to use your new updated values